# Funcion booleana c++ para encontrar numeros menores

Tags: c++

Codifique la definición de una función cuyo prototipo es:

```
bool sonTodosMenoresCincuenta(double u[NMAX] ,  int N);
```

La función recibe como argumento un arreglo unidimensionales u de tamaño NMAX, además la función recibe un entero N que representa la cantidad de elementos a usar dentro de los arreglo. La función debe devolver true si todos los elementos dentro del arreglo son menors a 50 y false en caso contrario.

Mi idea para resolver el problema fue la siguiente:

```
bool sonTodosMenoresCincuenta(double u[NMAX] ,  int N)
{
      for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
       if(u[i]<=50.0){
           return true;
           }
        else(u[i]>50.0){
           return false;
       }   
   }
}
```

Pero siempre me da 1111111111 de resultado y no estoy entendiendo bien por qué. Acepto desde links de algun libro o video o cualquier sugerencia que quieran aportar, gracias.

Comment: Quizás más bien sea como muestras los datos tras la ejecución. Recuerda que 1 significa true y 0 false. Por otro lado. Debes retornar true solo cuando se hayan comprobado los 50 números. Ahora mismo, lo único que estas haciendo es devolver true si el primer número que compruebas es true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se muy bien a qué te refieres con que te da como resultado 11111111 cuando la función retorna o true o false... Pero bueno. Si lo que quieres es que te retorne true si todos los elementos del array son menores de 50, lo que has hecho no funciona porque retorna true si el primer elemento del array es menor o igual que 50.0 y false en otro caso. Pero solo compruebas el primer elemento al hacer el return. Lo que necesitas sería algo como esto:

```
bool sonTodosMenoresCincuenta( double u[NMAX], int N) {
    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if( u[ i] > (double)50) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Compruebas cada elemento y en el momento en el que encuentres al menos uno mayor que 50, ya no se cumple la condición y la función termina con false. Si llegas al final del bucle sin haber encontrado ningún elemento mayor a 50, es que todos son menores o iguales a 50 y la función retorna true.

Answer (score 1):

> La función debe devolver true si todos los elementos dentro del arreglo son menores a 50 y false en caso contrario.

Este tipo de algoritmo se suele implementar asumiendo que el resultado será verdadero y devolviendo falso en caso de que un elemento no cumpla la restricción, porque basta con un elemento para que toda la condición sea falsa:

```
bool sonTodosMenoresCincuenta( double u[NMAX], int N) {
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(u[i]>50.0){
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Si llegamos a este punto, es que todos los elementos eran < 50
    return true;
}
```

Pero este tipo de función en que se pasa una formación y un tamaño está en desuso en C++, las implementaciones modernas reciben dos iteradores:

```
template <typename iterador>
bool sonTodosMenoresCincuenta(iterador inicio, iterador final) {
    for(;inicio != final; ++inicio){
        if (*inicio > 50.0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Si llegamos a este punto, es que todos los elementos eran < 50
    return true;
}
```

Que puede usarse así:

```
int main()
{
    double d[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    if (sonTodosMenoresCincuenta(d, d + 10)) {
        std::cout << "Yupi!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Pero esto es muy poco flexible ¿Y si queremos hacer otro tipo de comprobaciones sobre los elementos? Lo habitual es pasar un predicado a la función:

```
template <typename iterador, typename predicado>
bool sonTodos(iterador inicio, iterador final, predicado p) {
    for(;inicio != final; ++inicio){
        if (!p(*inicio)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Si llegamos a este punto, es que todos los elementos cumplen el predicado
    return true;
}
```

Que puede usarse así:

```
bool menorCincuenta(double d) {
    return d < 50.0;
}

int main()
{
    double d[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    // Pasando una función
    if (sonTodos(d, d + 10, menorCincuenta)) {
        std::cout << "Yupi!\n";
    }

    // Pasando una lambda
    if (sonTodos(d, d + 10, [](double d){ return d < 50.0; })) {
        std::cout << "Yipu!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Pero en lugar de reinventar la rueda podemos usar la [función `all_of` de la cabecera `<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of):

```
int main()
{
    double d[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    if (std::all_of(d, d + 10, [](double d){ return d < 50.; })) {
        std::cout << "Yupi!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Genial!!!! Me encantan tus respuestas!